# Do I need the command 'env' for setting a temporary environment variable?

Tags: c#, command-line, mono

What's the difference between the two lines of commands?

```
shy@nova:~/dev$ env TEST_VAR=demo mono test.exe
demo
shy@nova:~/dev$ TEST_VAR=demo mono test.exe
demo
shy@nova:~/dev$
```

test.exe simply writes the result of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_VAR"); to the console. As you see it works in both cases, with or without 'env'.

Is there any explanation for this? Can 'env' always be omitted or is it bad behavior to leave it out?

Comment: .. "Note that this use of env is often unnecessary since most shells support setting environment variables in front of a command:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia's `env` lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env):

> `env` is a shell command for Unix and Unix-like operating systems. It is used to either print a list of environment variables or **run another utility in an altered environment without having to modify the currently existing environment**.
>
> [...]
>
> To launch the X application xcalc and have it appear on a different display:
>
> ```
> env DISPLAY=foo.bar:1.0 xcalc
> ```
>
> **Note that this use of env is often unnecessary since most shells support setting environment variables in front of a command**:
>
> ```
> DISPLAY=foo.bar:1.0 xcalc
> ```

So, no, if your shell is one of those "most shells".

Answer (score 0):

try this source 
https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/env.1.asp.

To my knowledge most shells don't require ***env*** unless you want to set or alter an environment variable explicitly.